# Why doesn't Vandermonde's identity work in this case?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Given the identity [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), to me it seems that this should be true:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\binom{n+i} i\binom{2n-i}{n-i} = \binom{3n}{n}$$

But it seems that this is not the case.

It turns out that it is actually $$\sum_{i = 0}^{n}\binom{n+i} i\binom{2n-i-1}{n-i} = \binom{3n}{n}$$for $n\ge1$.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the above technically follow Vandermonde's identity?

Comment: The upper parameters in that identity's binomial coefficients are constant across values of the dummy variable.

Comment: @J.G.I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. If the form is m + n, can't we have n=n and m=2n so then m+n = 3n?

Comment: I'm talking about the dependence on the *dummy* variable $i$, for the terms on the other side of the equation.

Comment: @J.G. oh i see what you mean. I still don't exactly understand how adding the -1 results in the correct formula

Comment: I wonder if it helps to rewrite the identity as $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n+i}{n}\binom{2n-1-i}{n-1}=\binom{3n}{2n}$.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650426/combinatorial-proof-that-sum-0n-nk-choose-n2n-k-1-choose-n-1-3n-ch/3650644#3650644) I gave a combinatorial proof of the correct identity; it’s a little tricky, but it may help to explain why you need the $-1$ in the upper number.

Answer (score 3):

Here we have *[Chu-Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise.
The crucial point is that we have the bound variable $i$ not only as lower index, but also as upper index of the binomial coeffcient. Nevertheless we can *transform* the binomial coefficient using the binomial identity 
\begin{align*}
\binom{p+q-1}{q}=(-1)^q\binom{-p}{q}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and then we can apply Chu-Vandermonde's identity.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i = 0}^{n}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n+i} {i}\binom{2n-i-1}{n-i}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{-n-1}{i}(-1)^i\binom{-n}{n-i}(-1)^{n-i}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^n\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{-n-1}{i}\binom{-n}{n-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{-2n-1}{n}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{3n}{n}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2)     we apply the binomial identity (1) twice.
- In (3) we are ready to apply the Chu-Vandermonde identity.
- In (4)     we apply (1) again.